# Generating YAML file from existing JAVA Spring API

Tags: java, spring, api, yaml

Is there any way of generating YAML file from existing Soap based API build in JAVA Spring ?

I need to generate swagger definition file (YAML file) from existing Java spring API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Rest API above your Soap client and then just enable Swagger in the project. Here you can see how to add Swagger in your application [Setting Up Swagger 2 with a Spring REST API](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api).